# "visitors to somewhere"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

*"This is the results of a questionnaire that asked visitors to the Parkway Hotel how they rated the hotel's customer service".*

*"A visitor to the American Museum of Natural History here in New York will find a darkened corner in front of the Planetarium where several dozen video screens are installed."*

"***visitors to somewhere***" is that structure simply equal to "*visitors **of** that particular place*" ?

Comment: That's correct.  [*Visitors **to** the museum* is more idiomatic than *visitors **of** the museum*, actually.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=visitors+to+the%2Cvisitors+of+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvisitors%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvisitors%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: What about "Visitor of the night"?

Answer (score 1):

The choice reflects perspective.  If you're conveying that the museum is serving as "host", it would be "visitors **of** the museum", essentially a possessive, like "the museum's visitors".  From a location perspective, "of" is similar to "at"; it conveys a sense that you are writing from inside the museum and visitors are already there.

If "of" was used instead of "to", the "will find" might be different.  If you were talking about a general condition throughout the museum, it would be "visitors **of** the museum **find** it easy to navigate".  If you were talking about a specific exhibit that someone inside the museum still needs to locate in order to see, "visitors of the museum **will find** a darkened corner in front of the Planetarium..."

"Visitors **to** the museum" conveys more of a sense that you are writing from somewhere else, describing visitors going to the museum, in the sense of,  "People who go to the museum will find..." (they aren't actually "visitors" until they get there).